# Does this double type definition cause an access violation?

Tags: c, struct, types, typedef

I'm using the following struct type definition and according memory allocation:

```
typedef struct company_tag { struct company_tag *next;
                             <some other elements of the structure>
                           } company;

...
static company *freecompany;
company *ps;
ps = (company*)&freecompany;
ps->next = (struct company_tag*)malloc(sizeof(company));
...
```

At the end of my program, I end up with an access violation, and I'd like to know if this strange type definition can be related to it.
The things I call strange:

- Why are there two type defnitions (company_tag and company), is there any link/difference between them?
- Why are those two type definitions used in the allocation line? (What would be the problem with `(struct company*)malloc(sizeof(company));`, except for the "incomplete type is not allowed" error (by the way, is something incomplete here?)?)

Comment: Have you alloc'd `static company *freecompany;`?

Comment: `ps = (company*)&freecompany;` raises red flags. You are forcing `company**` into `company*`, and hide the error message with a cast.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> end up with an access violation

Because you have not allocated memory to `ps`  and trying to access `ps->next`

You need to allocate memory before access it.
May be what you want is as follow change required in your code:

```
static company freecompany;  //declare variable 
company *ps;
ps = &freecompany;
```

> Why are there two type defnitions (company_tag and company), is there
>   any link/difference between them?

There is no difference,  `typedef` which you can use to give a type, a new name.

Answer (score 2):

> Why are there two type defnitions (company_tag and company), is there any link/difference between them?

That's the whole idea of `typedef`

```
typedef struct company_tag { struct company_tag *next;
                         <some other elements of the structure>
                       } company;
```

You can use `company` now in place of the full form`struct company_tag` - this is not an issue.

---

> Why are those two type definitions used in the allocation line? (What would be the problem with (struct company*)malloc(sizeof(company));

```
ps->next = (struct company_tag*)malloc(sizeof(company));
```

Actually this line can (should) be written as:

```
ps->next = malloc(sizeof(company));
```

---

The problem looks to be at these lines:

```
static company *freecompany;
company *ps;
ps = (company*)&freecompany;
```

Perhaps you use pointer where you shouldn't, which means:

```
static company freecompany;
company *ps = &freecompany;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static company *freecompany;
company *ps;
ps = (company*)&freecompany;
```

This code is nonsense and incorrect, you never allocate a `company` object anywhere and the cast is wrong. It is hard to even guess what this code was supposed to do, why is there a static pointer variable?

> Why are there two type defnitions (company_tag and company), is there any link/difference between them?

This is so that you can declare a pointer to a structure with the same type, from inside the very same structure. So `struct company_tag *next;` means the very same thing as `company* next;`. It just has to be written in the former manner inside the struct declaration, as you are still declaring the struct when you are typing that line and at that point the compiler doesn't know what `company` is yet.

> Why are those two type definitions used in the allocation line?

Because whoever wrote this code was confused. It should have been

```
ps->next = malloc(sizeof(company));
```

But that assumes that `ps` itself is already pointing at allocated space! This is not the case in the code posted.